# from torchvision import transforms run error

Tags: python, torchvision

```
from PIL import Image
from torchvision import transforms
img_path = "dataset/train/ants/5650366_e22b7e1065.jpg"
img = Image.open(img_path)
print(img)
tensor_trans = transforms.ToTensor()    # 相当于是转换工具tool
tensor_img = tensor_trans(img)          # output = tool(input)
print(tensor_img)
```

[image]

Many of the explanations I looked up were that the pytorch and Torchvision versions were inconsistent, but mine was

[image]

I don't know how to solve it

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you installed the packages and what type of package manager you are using? This is important to give you the right answer.

Comment: I tried it in the evening, firstly，conda uninstall pytorch，secondly，conda install pytorch==1.9.0 torchvision==0.10.0 torchaudio==0.9.0 cudatoolkit=10.2 -c pytorch，lastly，problem solved successfully,thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
conda activate pytorch
conda uninstall pytorch
conda install pytorch==1.9.0 torchvision==0.10.0 torchaudio==0.9.0 cudatoolkit=10.2 -c pytorch
```

I downgraded the pytorch version and solved the problem successfully